# Tsql aggregate group by results under specific threshold as "others"

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an aggregate query which gives to me these results:

```
289         Andria - BT
97          N/A
97          Barletta - BT
47          Cerignola - FG
34          Corato - BA
33          Trani - BT
21          Bari - BA
19          Bitonto - BA
18          Bisceglie - BT
18          San Ferdinando di Puglia - BT
15          Foggia - FG
14          Molfetta - BA
14          Terlizzi - BA
12          Altamura - BA
9           San Severo - RA
9           Trinitapoli - BT
8           Margherita di Savoia - BT
7           Lucera - FG
6           Giovinazzo - BA
5           Capurso - BA
5           Minervino Murge - BT
5           Spinazzola - BT
5           Venosa - PZ
4           Stornara - FG
4           Milano - PG
4           Palo del Colle - BA
```

I would like to sum all values under some thresold (for example 10) in a single row; something like

```
289         Andria - BT
97          N/A
97          Barletta - BT
47          Cerignola - FG
34          Corato - BA
33          Trani - BT
21          Bari - BA
19          Bitonto - BA
18          Bisceglie - BT
18          San Ferdinando di Puglia - BT
15          Foggia - FG
14          Molfetta - BA
14          Terlizzi - BA
12          Altamura - BA
<SUM>       OTHER
```

The query is basically something like:

```
select count(ID) as Count, ISNULL(Description, 'N/A') as City
from 
Table    
group by Description
```

how can i achieve this result?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Move the counting to a cte. Select its rows where count >= 10 and UNION ALL with the sum for rows having count < 10.

```
with cte as
(
    select count(ID) as Count, ISNULL(Description, 'N/A') as City
    from Table    
    group by Description
)
select * from cte where Count >= 10
UNION ALL
select SUM(count), 'Other' from cte where Count < 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

```
SELECT SUM(CountID),City
FROM(
       select count(ID) as CountID, 
              CASE WHEN count(ID) < 10 
                   THEN 'Other' 
                   ELSE ISNULL(Description, 'N/A')
              END as City

      from Table    
      group by Description
)m
Group BY City
```

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit unclear to me, but I'll give you to queries, which are slightly different. Choose wichever satisfies you.

All you need is `HAVING` clause:

```
select count(ID) as Count, ISNULL(Description, 'N/A') as City
from 
Table    
group by Description
having count(ID) > 10
```

Or you can use this query:

```
select count(ID), City from (
    select ID, ISNULL(Description, 'N/A') as City
    from Table    
    where ID > 10
) as A
group by City
```

Comment: Yes, but how to sum up "other" values?